# Connected subspace of a disconnected space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

My friend and I can't figure out something that seems pretty simple. So any help would be appreciated :)

Does there exist a topological space $X$ and a subspace $A \subseteq X$ such that:

1. $X$ is connected;
2. $A$ is connected;
3. $\forall a \in A$ the subspace $A\smallsetminus \{a\}$ is connected **and** the subspace $X \smallsetminus \{a\}$ is not connected.

**Edit**:

To make it less trivial, can we find an "interesting" example of a subspace $A$? Suppose one with non-empty interior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is at least a trivial sort of example. Let $X$ by the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan), and let $A=\{p\}$, where $p$ is the [dispersion point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_point) $\left\langle\frac12,\frac12\right\rangle$. (I take the empty set to be connected, since it is not the union of two non-empty, pairwise disjoint open sets.)

**Added:** Here’s a much better example. Let $X=S^1\times\Bbb R$ with the following metric: for $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle\in Y$ let

$$d\big(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle\big)=\begin{cases}
|y_0-y_1|,&\text{if }x_0=x_1\\
|y_0|+|y_1|+\rho(x_0,x_1),&\text{if }x_0\ne x_1\;,
\end{cases}$$

where $\rho$ is any metric on the circle $S^1$ generating the usual topology, e.g., the restriction of the Euclidean metric in the plane. Let $A=S^1\times\{0\}$. $X$, $A$, and $A\setminus\{a\}$ for $a\in A$ are all path-connected and hence connected. However, for $a=\langle x,0\rangle\in A$ the set $X\setminus\{a\}$ has three components, $\{x\}\times(0,\to)$, $\{x\}\times(\leftarrow,0)$, and $(S^1\setminus\{a\})\times\Bbb R$, so it’s not connected.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: In your case of $A$, why not simply choose $X$ to be an interval?

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed this one.. Though I hope there's a less trivial example somewhere out there... :)

Comment: @Ludolila: You’re welcome. I’m actually leaning a bit more towards trying to prove that if $|A|>1$, there isn’t an example.

Comment: @Giraffe: You could; but the first thing that occurred to me was a dispersion point, so I gave an example of one.

Comment: @Ludolila: Despite my pessimism, I found a much better example.

Comment: Do you mean $(S^1\setminus\{x\})\times\mathbb R$ in the last line?.

Comment: @Stefan: I did indeed; thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

Brian has already shown how this is possible even for infinite subsets $A$ in metric spaces. I'm writing my example, however, which came to my mind before Brian's edit, and which I like due to its simple description.

In the real line identify all points between $0$ and $1$, so $X=\mathbb R/(0,1)$. Let $b$ denote the equivalence class of the interval, and $A=\{0,b\}$. Clearly $X$ is connected. $A$ has the Sierpiński topology, so it is connected, too. But removing any point of $A$ disconnects $X$.

A finite version of this example would be $X=\{-1,0,b,1\}$ with the topology $\tau$ generated by the base $\{\{-1\},\{-1,0,b\},\{b\},\{b,1\}\}$. Let $A=\{0,b\}$. Then every point in $A$ divides $X$ into two components.